# JMeter: HTTP Header Manager and the Authorization-field (MD5-sess)

Tags: authorization, md5, jmeter

I'm using JMeter 2.4 and I want to test a site that uses the MD5-sess algorithm. As JMeter can only handle basic authentication and writing a JMeter plug-in seems to be difficult (the tutorial to this states so) I wrote a small servlet that generates the `cnonce`, `response` and `nc` fields for me. I call this servlet like a normal request with the digest and extract those three variables.

So far no problem.

Then I tried to create a HTTP sampler to call the actual target service and assigned a HTTP Header Manager as a child. There I defined the header field "Authorization" to hold the authorization string. I tested this and noticed that the header field didn't appear in the request. After some googling I learned that [the authorization field is ignored since the HTTP Authorization Manager handles this](http://www.mail-archive.com/jmeter-user@jakarta.apache.org/msg27518.html). However, JMeter doesn't know of MD5-sess.

If I use any header name other than "Authorization" the header field appears properly.

Therefore, my question is: What do I do now? How do I force JMeter to let me set the authorization header?

Comment: You may try asking on the Nabble forum where the Jmeter developers hang out if you don't get an answer on SO. http://jmeter.512774.n5.nabble.com/JMeter-User-f512775.html

Comment: @BlackGaff: thanks, I will check there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We solved this by using plan C (or was it D?). Since Jmeter is open source, we took a look at [HTTPSampler](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSampler.html) and applied the MD5-stuff there.